# Fetch record by Year

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a form with a text field, where the user will provide the year only and MySQL data should return all the data for the given year. But in MySQL database, the `date` is given in `date(yyyy-mm-dd)` format.

Can anyone suggest the SQL query which will fetch all the data for that particular year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this one, use the MySQL `YEAR` function.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE YEAR(dateCOlumn) = 2012
```

so in the given example, the server will select all records where year is equal to 2012.

**UPDATE 1**

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c747/2)

## [YEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 
  select * from tablename where year(columname) = 'whatever the year is';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and Derek's?

Comment: Difference of 2 mins, in which case we were both typing the same answer, except that mine came 2 minutes later :)